㊗️スタック・オーバーフロー 10周年！
2024年12月に、スタック・オーバーフローは10周年を迎えました。この10年間、質問や回答、投票、コミュニティの構築に貢献してくださったみなさまに心から感謝し、お祝い申し上げます。この記念すべき節目をお祝いしたいと思います！
 イベント概要
期間中、以下の条件で選ばれた各部門の上位 2 名（合計 4 名）に、素敵なプレゼントをお届けします
 対象部門

期間中に投稿され、最も高い投票スコアを得た「質問」の投稿者

期間中に投稿され、最も高い投票スコアを得た「回答」の投稿者


 スケジュール

投稿期間：2024年12月17日〜2025年1月16日

投票期間：2024年12月17日〜2025年1月16日（※2025年1月17日の UTC 0時時点までの投票が対象です）

結果発表：2025年1月17日


 賞品
スタック・オーバーフロー10周年オリジナル風呂敷をプレゼント！

10周年という特別な瞬間を、みなさまと一緒にお祝いできることを本当に嬉しく思います。✨素晴らしい質問や回答にたくさんの「プラス投票」を送りながら、楽しいひとときをお過ごしください！スタック・オーバーフローユーザーのみなさまに、これからもたくさんの幸せと成功が訪れますように！
